# What is the correct way to ask someone if he or she can do something?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, giving-and-receiving

I want to ask someone if he can translate something for me. However I do not know what the correct way of asking is. I do not want to ask if he wants to do it, but rather if he has the knowledge to do so. So something along the lines of: Do you know how to translate this, but with 'can' instead of 'Do you know'

I thought of something like:

```
これはできを訳しますか
```

However I do not think it is right.

So my question will then be:

What is the correct way to ask someone if he or she can do something? With the usage of `できます` (If possible)

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55267/the-word-that-translate-to-can-in-a-sentence/55269#55269

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Should I close my question  or leave it here for refference purposes?

Comment: I've re-read your question. It's similar but not quite the same. This question should remain open.

Comment: `... but rather if he has the knowledge to do so. So something along the lines of: Do you know how to translate this, but with 'can'... ` <-- So, you want to ask "Can you...?" in the sense of "Are you able to... / Do you have the ability of doing...? (これを/が訳せますか？)" rather than asking for a favor from someone like "Would you do... for me, please? (これを訳してくれませんか。)", right?

Answer (score 1):

One important grammar rule that pertains to this is how to ask for a favor from someone. This requires the knowledge and use of 上｛あ｝げる・くれる・もらう verbs.

> 上{あ}げる -> I give to you
>
> くれる -> You give to me
>
> もらう -> I receive from you

Stemming from this, what you're asking for is for a translation, but you're wondering if it is alright to ask for this. So, let's start with the English variant of the question:

> Will you translate this for me?

If we examine this sentence first, you're asking for the favor of translation. Basically, you're asking to be given a translation as a favor. Therefore, you'd want to use くれる as your verb of request. To add additional politeness, you may add よければ or any such phrase at the start of the question to further indicate that you're asking this as a favor and not as a demand:

> (よければ、)これを訳して**くれません**か。
>   (If it's alright with you,) will you (**Won't you**) translate this for me?